# In Flutter, can I use only one controller to retrieve values from more than one TextField?

Tags: flutter

I've been following this Tutorial: https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input

It looks like there's one controller for one TextField. Can I use one controller to retrieve the value of multiple TextFields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The controller holds the current value (in `controller.text`) which is why you need more than one.

It also holds the selection (which characters are highlighted if any), which will also be different between different fields.